# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.oddsshark.com/mlb/odds');

echo $html;
```

When ehcoed, the error message in the title of this question appears? I've had problems that are similar to this before. In all cases, I didn't actually need to increase the memoery in php.ini. Rather, there was a missing curly bracket that was needed to close a loop. This page that I'm requesting via the file_get_html function appears fine in my browser, but it just won't let me echo the html via php.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is this `file_get_html()` function?

Comment: Did you try using `file_get_contents()` instead of `file_get_html()`?

Comment: Yeah, but that's not compatible with an html parser that I'm using.

Comment: @Kolink It's part of [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: Yesss!. It is, actually

Comment: Also beware with Simple HTML DOM Parser:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm#memory_leak

Comment: You say the error occur when you echo (as opposed to when you call the file_get_html() function ) ?

Comment: That's correct. I only get an error message when echoing it.

Comment: Use DOMDocument / SimpleXML instead. They are better memory optimized (and Simple HTML DOM Parser is really not necessary any longer for most PHP installments).

Comment: What's the size of the variable content ? Can you to echo strlen($html);die(); ? Is $html an object or a string ? Some object contain recursive reference making them unprintable ( they generate infinite content)

Comment: I would rather say that something is wrong when it comes to getting file contents. Function is "looped" and memory is  exhausted.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm guessing too. Know of any good alternatives to the simple html dom parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a library that is more memory optimized, simple HTML DOM is just not necessary any longer:

```
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTMLFile('http://www.oddsshark.com/mlb/odds');
echo $html->saveHTML();
```

More suggestions are available with the reference question about that topic:

- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)

Comment: '-­>:' ... the : is a typo, right ? This is a good answer, but I don't see the use for using DOMDocument just to print the raw source of an HTTP request, look like it will generate a useless object and involve useless processing...

Comment: @FMaz008: Yes, the colon `:` is a typo. Sure :) - Fixed + Thx. - For the example: This is the example the user does in the question, so I actually did not judge about how high- or low-level it is, just showing that other libraries are able to read a document into memory without triggering the memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

increase your memory limit in php.ini file

search for

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M
```

in your php.ini file and increase it to 512M

Comment: If it takes more than 33MB to load a 300kb HTML file, there's a problem that's bigger than just a memory limit.

Comment: It can also be done by setting ini_set('memory_limit', '128M') directly in PHP file.

Comment: The problem has probably to do with the internal processing of the HTML so either fixing the code is an option or increasing the limit.

Comment: Unless you modify the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser library, it gives up if the file is more than 600KB, to avoid using too much memory.

Comment: @Kolink: The problem is the library. And you can't expect to get it actually fixed because it's superfluous in times of DOMDocument and friends. So suggesting to increase the memory limit - even if not very creative - actually sounds not like the worst suggestion here. The alternative is to replace the library (and I would go with that normally).

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think this usage justify increasing the memory. If it go over, it's because there is a problem : Simple HTML DOM  Parser is known to suffer from memory leak.

If you just need to retrieve the content of a remote page using HTTP, just do the following. This is the simplest and most resource efficient way I know to retrieve content from a remote page:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

If you need to do more advance queries, you may look into cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score -2):

Edit your php.ini file

```
memory_limit=512M
```

OR add a line in your PHP file:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

And the error will get resolved.
Note: You can put your value instead of `512M`.

Comment: Unless, for whatever reason, it takes more than 2GB of memory.